# ScalarDB on ComosDB Configuration

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, scalardb

I'd like to estimate the costs of Azure CosmosDB on Scalar DB.
CosmosDB requires the following parameters. But these parameters are not ScalarDB parameters.

- API
- Number of Regions
- Multi-region writes
- Default consistency
- Indexing policy
- Total data stored in transactional store
- Use Analyltical Store
- Workload mode
- Item Size
- Number of properties
- Point reads/sec
- Creates/sec
- Updates/sec
- Deletes/sec
- Queries/sec
- Average RU charge per query

So, should we set which configuration and can we above parameters map to Scalar DB parameters?

I confirm the following questions.
About Configuration

- API -> Cassandra
- Number of Regions -> If we need to write into multi-region, set over 2.
- Multi-region writes -> If the multi-regions is over 2, set to "Enabled"
- Default consistency -> Strong. But CosmosDB could satisfy transactions across multi-partitions. It is covered by Scalar DB.

About API calls
Scalar DB APIs vs ComosDB APIs

- Put: Insert without condition => createItem()
- Put: Insert with condition => readItem() -> not exists -> createItem()
- Put: Update with condition => readItem() -> if conditions are satisfied -> merge columns -> replaceItem()
- Get -> readItem()
- Delete without condition => deleteItem()
- Delete with condition => readItem() -> if conditions are satisfied -> deleteItem()
- Scan => container.queryItems()

I think ScalarDB has some operations before the above operations which check the transaction state. So, Does Scalar DB require more ComosDB API Calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following settings.

- API: Core (SQL) (not Cassandra)
- Number of Regions: 1 (since Strong
  consistency doesn't support multi-region)
- Multi-region writes:
  Disabled (since Strong consistency doesn't support multi-region)
- Default consistency: Strong

For what Scalar DB API calls which Cosmos DB API,
please check the code.

Comment: It is important information that Scalar DB does not support Multi-region writes...

Comment: It's a limitation of Cosmo DB and not the limitation of Scalar DB, so if Cosmos DB supports multi-region writes with Strong consistency, we can support it without any change.